# Ansible keytool: command not found

Tags: ansible, elastic-stack

I developed a task to simply execute a command on remote host:

```
- name: generate ssl
  shell: ./example.sh
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/example-pki-scripts
```

The example.sh file execute some scripts in order: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-ssl/tree/master/example-pki-scripts

then when I deploy this task on a remote host the following error appears:

```
fatal: [efk1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "./example.sh",
    "delta": "0:00:00.213500",
    "end": "2017-01-20 12:02:10.703895",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "./example.sh",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": "/tmp/example-pki-scripts",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": true
        },
        "module_name": "command"
    },
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2017-01-20 12:02:10.490395",
    "stderr": "Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key\n.+++\n.......+++\nwriting new private key to 'ca/root-ca/private/root-ca.key'\n-----\nUsing configuration from etc/root-ca.conf\nCheck that the request matches the signature\nSignature ok\nCertificate Details:\n        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)\n        Validity\n            Not Before: Jan 20 11:02:10 2017 GMT\n            Not After : Jan 20 11:02:10 2027 GMT\n        Subject:\n            domainComponent           = com\n            domainComponent           = example\n            organizationName          = Example Com Inc.\n            organizationalUnitName    = Example Com Inc. Root CA\n            commonName                = Example Com Inc. Root CA\n        X509v3 extensions:\n            X509v3 Key Usage: critical\n                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign\n            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical\n                CA:TRUE\n            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: \n                EB:DC:70:FA:90:59:4A:C3:09:E3:73:80:92:E0:EE:70:9A:77:48:62\n            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: \n                keyid:EB:DC:70:FA:90:59:4A:C3:09:E3:73:80:92:E0:EE:70:9A:77:48:62\n\nCertificate is to be certified until Jan 20 11:02:10 2027 GMT (3652 days)\n\nWrite out database with 1 new entries\nData Base Updated\nGenerating a 2048 bit RSA private key\n..............................................................................+++\n......................+++\nwriting new private key to 'ca/signing-ca/private/signing-ca.key'\n-----\nUsing configuration from etc/root-ca.conf\nCheck that the request matches the signature\nSignature ok\nCertificate Details:\n        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)\n        Validity\n            Not Before: Jan 20 11:02:10 2017 GMT\n            Not After : Jan 20 11:02:10 2027 GMT\n        Subject:\n            domainComponent           = com\n            domainComponent           = example\n            organizationName          = Example Com Inc.\n            organizationalUnitName    = Example Com Inc. Signing CA\n            commonName                = Example Com Inc. Signing CA\n        X509v3 extensions:\n            X509v3 Key Usage: critical\n                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign\n            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical\n                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0\n            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: \n                19:19:0A:28:78:33:A8:04:A9:5F:62:81:CA:3D:9F:8A:1F:97:00:6F\n            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: \n                keyid:EB:DC:70:FA:90:59:4A:C3:09:E3:73:80:92:E0:EE:70:9A:77:48:62\n\nCertificate is to be certified until Jan 20 11:02:10 2027 GMT (3652 days)\n\nWrite out database with 1 new entries\nData Base Updated\n./gen_root_ca.sh: line 72: keytool: command not found",
    "stdout": "Root CA generated\nSigning CA generated",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Root CA generated",
        "Signing CA generated"
    ],
    "warnings": []
}
```

so as you cam see the problem is line 72: keytool: command not found, but when I execute the same script example.sh on the machine locally it generates ssl keys with no problem.

The exact line where ansible stucks is:

```
cat ca/root-ca.pem | keytool \
    -import \
    -v \
    -keystore truststore.jks   \
    -storepass $TS_PASS  \
    -noprompt -alias root-ca-chain
```

Answer (score 4):

Use full path to the `keytool` executable in your script.

Ansible uses non-interactive, non-login shell session and shells do not source the same rc files as for interactive/login sessions thus the value of `PATH` differs.

Other solutions include: specifying `PATH` manually in the `environment` delaraction, or wrapping the command in a call to `bash`.